# OnClick event that sends email to admin with page URL

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am new to this site and looking forward to an amazing experience.

I have a classifieds website and I need a new feature to report ads as 'spam'. These are basically ads with suspicious/illegal content. I want to place a button on the ad pages, which simply says: Report as spam. Whenever any user clicks on that button, an email is sent to the site admin with the URL of the page. That's it. How can I implement this in PHP? Also, I want to ensure that the page is not reloaded so an Ajax solution would be preferred. Thank you!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a code writing service though- you'll need to do research, try to get it to work, and if you can't come back here and post your code. We'll be happy to help.

Comment: What do you know about implementing AJAX? How are your jQuery skills?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript framework like jQuery, YUI or ExtJS for the AJAX request send to a php page that sends you an e-mail

your codes would be like this:

**Javascript**

```
function reportAbuse() {
       var page = '<?php echo base64_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>';
       //jQuery like $('#hiddenDiv').load('report.php?page=' + page);
    }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$page = base64_decode($_GET['page']);
//use PHP mail() function to mail the page to your e-mail
?>
```

Above example is not save you should prevent users from accessing report.php too much (or you get spammed) and if you read in to jQuery I would advise to send the information via $_POST instead of $_GET.
But this shoud get you started.